# How to write a conditional array operation on a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

Suppose I have a DataFrame, in which one of the columns (we'll call it 'power') holds integer values from 1 to 10000.  I would like to produce a numpy array which has, for each row, a value indicating whether the corresponding row of the DataFrame has a value in the 'power' column which is greater than 9000.

I could do something like this:

```
def categorize(frame):
    return np.array(frame['power']>9000)
```

This will give me a boolean array which can be tested against with True and False.  However, suppose I want the contents of the array to be 1 and -1, rather than True and False.  How can I accomplish this without having to iterate through each row in the frame?

For background, the application is preparing data for binary classification via machine learning with scikit-learn.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where` for this type of stuff.

Consider the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': range(20)})
df['even'] = df.a % 2 == 0
```

So now `even` is a boolean column. To create an array the way you like, you can use

```
np.where(df.even, 1, -1)
```

You can assign this back to the DataFrame, if you like:

```
df['foo'] = np.where(df.even, 1, -1)
```

---

See the [`pandas` cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html) further for this sort of stuff.